# currying function instead of if condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Tried to use curry function to write if condition (without "if" "true" and "false"). Have no idea how to do it right! Can anyone help and show me how to do it?

```
const True = () => {};
const False = () => {};
const If = True => False => ifFunction(True)(False);

const ifFunction = If(True);
ifFunction('1')('2'); // 1

console.log(If(True)('1')('2'));  // 1
console.log(If(False)('1')('2')); // 2
```

It should return 1 or 2 depends on which function is getting pass to if condition. But this code does not work at all.

Comment: Look for the [Lambda Calculus](https://medium.com/@ahlechandre/lambda-calculus-with-javascript-897f7e81f259).

Comment: Also, take a look at [church booleans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_Booleans)

Comment: For the record, [here is Ramda's implementation of `ifElse`](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.26.1/source/ifElse.js) which implements `ifElse(conditionFn, trueBranchFn, falseBranchFn)`. The library uses a simple conditional operator as the implementation (simplified): `conditionFn() ? trueBranchFn() : falseBranchFn()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using [Church_Booleans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_Booleans), you could use the following functions.

```js
const
    TRUE = a => b => a,
    FALSE = a => b => b,
    IF = p => a => b => p(a)(b);

console.log(IF(TRUE)('1')('2'));  // 1
console.log(IF(FALSE)('1')('2')); // 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to implement `True`, `False`, and `If` without using any control flow statements like `if...else` or `switch..case`, control flow expressions like `?:`, or higher-order functions.

```js
const True  = 1;
const False = 0;

const If = Bool => Then => Else => [Else, Then][Bool];

console.log(If(True)('1')('2'));  // 1
console.log(If(False)('1')('2')); // 2
```

This is a [defunctionalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defunctionalization) of the Church encoding solution. Hence, it's more efficient.

Comment: You can accept truthy/falsy values if you modify `[Bool]` to `[Number(!!Bool)]`.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```js
const True = () => true;
const False = () => false;
const If = exp => exp() ? a => b => a : a => b => b;

console.log(If(True)('1')('2'));  // 1
console.log(If(False)('1')('2')); // 2
```

Comment: thank you. but I trying to do it without "if" (even ternary)